# How operator overloading can return a third class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have the following classes in different files

```
class Fruit():   
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if type(self) == type(otro):
            ## PROBLEM AREA  ##################################################
            return type(self)(self.value + other.value)
        else:
          raise Exception.SumError(self, other) # Custom exception
    
    def __repr__(self):
      return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.value})"
```

The Fruit () class is the base class, from which the following two child classes inherit

```
class Pear(Fruit):
    """docs"""
    def __init__(self, quantity=0):
        super().__init__(quantity)
        self.unit = "Pe"
```

```
class Apple(Fruit):
    """docs"""
    def __init__(self, quantity=0):
        super().__init__(quantity)
        self.unit = "Ap"
```

The class required in the result is the following:

```
class Market_List():
    """docs"""    
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
```

Currently I can add Pears() with Pears() and Apples() with Apples(), my question is how do I make adding Pears() with Apples() throw me a Market_List() object. I have already tried to use `from market_list import Market_List` at the beginning of the Fruit() class, but wanting to do the same in the Market_List() class to do the inverse operation then it enters a loop and gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

Put the inports in the init methods, then the code will not run at module load time and you will not get the error

Comment: I put in the Fruit() init `from market_list import Market_List` and `
        if type(self) == type(other):
            return type(self)(self.value + other.value)
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return Market_List(self.value + other.value)
`
And it yield `Market_list is not define`

Comment: Did you do it for all classes where you have this circular import structure (Fruit + MarketList)?
That is saying that your import did not work.
Also in python you can have two classes in one file, like Fruit + MarketList

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I had to import them inside the __add__ methods for it to work